# Adding custom index for sorting of collections in Plone 5

Tags: plone, plone-5.x

In order to rank my plone pages by a number of positive ratings that the users have given them I am using the cioppino.twothumbs addon and now want to sort a collection by number of positive ratings.

I want to add a custom index from the Plone 5 addon [cioppino.twothumbs](https://github.com/collective/cioppino.twothumbs/) as sortable index to Plone collections. The index is called **positive_ratings** and registered by [catalog.xml](https://github.com/collective/cioppino.twothumbs/blob/master/cioppino/twothumbs/profiles/base/catalog.xml) of cioppino.twothumbs. In my custom branch of the addon I added the code mentioned in the [documentation](http://docs.plone.org/develop/plone/functionality/collections.html):

```
<records interface="plone.app.querystring.interfaces.IQueryField"
       prefix="plone.app.querystring.field.positive_ratings">
<value key="title">Positive Ratings</value>
<value key="description">total number of positive ratings</value>
<value key="enabled">False</value>
<value key="sortable">True</value>
<value key="operations">
</value>
<value key="group">Metadata</value>
```

to the [registry.xml](https://github.com/collective/cioppino.twothumbs/blob/master/cioppino/twothumbs/profiles/plone5/registry.xml) of the addon. Unfortunately I have this index not visible as sortable on the **Add Collection** page, although it is available as additional column of the Collection.

This Question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36734143/how-to-add-new-collection-criteria-in-plone-5), but unlike the user there I have not modified the plone.app.querystring source code, but my custom branch of cioppino.twothumbs, as suggested by the answer.

Comment: Not sure about the ``enabled`` to ``False`` in your source

Comment: Try the following: open http://server/plonesite/@@qsOptions, check if your index is listed in sortable_indexes. If it is not, put a pdb here: https://github.com/plone/plone.app.querystring/blob/master/plone/app/querystring/registryreader.py#L118 and see what happens, if it is, check if the corresponding json section is similar to others or not.

Comment: so the index is not listed on qsOptions. Putting a pdb as you intended told me that the index is not listed in the values dictionary. Any ideas how to track this problem further?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code was completely correct, however I forgot to **rerun the installation of the addon** for the registry to get updated. This solved the problem completely and enabled the sorting of collections by this value.